# HAProxy setup without using OPS manager

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, cloud-foundry

I want to setup Load balancer for my application in PCF. The HAProxy load balancer looks promising. But I do not have access to the OPS manager to set it up as given in the link.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-0/customizing/custom-load-balancer.html

Is there any other alternate way to achieve load balancing option (preferably HAProxy) without using the OPS manager?

Comment: Why is it that you do not want or cannot use Ops Manager?  What is the state of your deployment now?  Is it complete & working properly?

Comment: As a developer, I do not access to it in my enterprise. And its not getting me anywhere trying to get access to it.

Comment: HAProxy is used in sandbox or dev environments. Most enterprises have load balancer and proxies already in place. So, traffic is often routed from those load balancers to the PCF.

Comment: The question I have, you mentioned `load balancer for your apps` - what do you mean by that? If your apps are running on PCF, you shouldn't have to wonder about it. Are you asking the question as a platform operator or application developer?